# How do I install mCrypt on windows

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I downloaded a Laravel test website, but when I go to view it, it prompts me with this error

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

Now, I know that Mcrypt has no future and whatever, but I really need it for an upcoming project. The thing is, **I have no idea how to install it.** All tutorials i found are on linux or mac. I am on PHP 7.2.4.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you Googled "mcrypt for PHP 7.2 on windows"? I know there are some third party repositories on Linux (since mcrypt has been removed since it's old and insecure) but installing it is _a very bad idea_. It's better to upgrade/fix the application so it doesn't depend on old, insecure and removed libraries.

Comment: are you working on local windows system? if yes which software you are using wammp or xammp?